# windows phone 8 - webbrowser display reverse words

Tags: html, windows-phone-8

I am trying to display a Right-to-left website (farsi/persian language) in a webbrowser in windows phone 8. but It display incorrect words. website is html5 and display correctly in phone IE but when I open it in a webbrowser control it show reverse words like this image:

[image]

correct order is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the FlowDirection property in your web browser control to RightToLeft.